# DOMDocument + DOMDocument

Tags: php, dom

Есть два объекта:

```
$doc = new DOMDocument('1.0', 'utf-8');
$doc->loadXML($xml);
$root = $doc->getElementsByTagName('body')->item(0);

$signdoc = new DOMDocument('1.0', 'utf-8');
$node_s  = $signdoc->createElement('signature');
$signdoc->appendChild($node_s);
```

Необходимо добавить узел **signature** в узел **body**

Так

```
$signature = $signdoc->documentElement;
$root->appendChild($signature);
```

почему-то упорно не прокатывает... Думаю элемент одного объекта нельзя вставить в элемент другого или что-то типа того.

Как-то можно решить проблему?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для этого нужно использовать [ImportNode](http://www.php.net/manual/ru/domdocument.importnode.php).

```
$signature = $signdoc->documentElement;
$signatureImported = $root->importNode($signature, true);
$root->appendChild($signatureImported);
```